# Regex find char '.' except for words starting with @

Tags: javascript, python, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

assuming the following sentence:

this is @sys.any and. here @names hello. and good.bye

how would I find all the '.' besides the ones appearing in words that start with @?

disclaimer, been playing at regex101 for over 2 hours now after reading a few answers on SO and other forums.

Comment: How important is it that the solution actually involves regex? You could do this in Python with a list comprehension and a handful of string methods.

Answer (score 2):

`(^|\s)(\w*(\.))+` - this may satisfy the sample text you've posted. You can find all '.' in third group

UPDATE: if in your text you have words, started with any other symbol, for instance, `#asd.qwe.zxc`, you can improve your reg exp:

`(^|\s)[^@]?(\w*(\.))+`

Comment: outstanding, ill further test use this regex. as for now this works for the example given. if anyone can think of edge cases to counter this answer I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: I found an edge case where this regex doesnt work, https://regex101.com/r/FtjRfL/1  , as you can see in the first work 'sys.a@ny.and.' I would have expected it to find all the '.' since the @ isn't at the start of the word.

Comment: @DanielNetzer what symbols are expected to be in words except '@'?

Comment: the only symbol that matters is '@', anything else is considered ok.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `^@|\s\w*(\.)+` may be used to only find and match periods without @.

See a live example for reference: http://rubular.com/r/gfVY3j16Rx

Comment: thats working as intended as far as i understood OP? @splash58

Comment: not really, I need the '.', not the words before them.

Comment: You want to look at the match groups, not the parsed text in match results. It only matches (i.e will only match output your periods), but displays as having found the text as criteria (not having @) before your periods.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/FtjRfL/1, as you can see in the first word 'sys.a@ny.and.' I would have expected it to find all the '.' since the @ isn't at the start of the word.